# Python requests module working in postman but on with python Invalid request body/header

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

I am using the postman tool to send the requests to the api server and trying to get the code snip-it from code section of postman, but somehow the same code is not working with python

this is the code :

```css
import requests
import json

url = "http://127.0.0.1:3333/api/v1/solve"

payload={'FileLocation': '/var/opt/rcm_dms/reg'}
files=[
  ('regChallengeFile',('gudsgtcnsrk_reg_challenge.json',open('/home/system/Music/gudsgtcnsrk_reg_challenge.json','rb'),'application/json'))
]
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)


output : {"statusCode":"DM-6-4002","statusMessage":"Invalid request body/header"}\n
```

```html
I am using the postman tool to send the requests to the api server and trying to get the code snip-it from code section of postman, but somehow the same code is not working with python 

this is the code :
```

output : {"statusCode":"DM-6-4002","statusMessage":"Invalid request body/header"}\n

What is wrong in this example , any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes should be on both side of key FileLocation `payload={'FileLocation': '/var/opt/rcm_dms/reg'}` instead of `payload={FileLocation': '/var/opt/rcm_dms/reg'}`.

If you still get the error, check the format of value assigned in files variable i.e.,`[('regChallengeFile',('gudsgtcnsrk_reg_challenge.json',open('/home/system/Music/gudsgtcnsrk_reg_challenge.json','rb'),'application/json'))]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out , that was the mistake which i made while adding it here in stackoverflow,

This is still in same shape, 

import requests
import json

url = "http://127.0.0.1:3333/api/v1/solve"

payload={'FileLocation': '/var/opt/rcm_dms/reg'}
files=[
  ('regChallengeFile',('gudsgtcnsrk_reg_challenge.json',open('/home/system/Music/gudsgtcnsrk_reg_challenge.json','rb'),'application/json'))
]
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)